# The best use of battery power

Tags: batteries, 5v, 3.3v

My project involves a number of components. Some are 3.3v and some are 5v

The project must be powered by 8 AA batteries.

Most of the time the components will be in a low power state.  But they will all turn on at the same time and then off again at the same time. With the exception of 2 servos. One 5v and 1 3v. They will be on almost all the time.

My plan is to combine the batteries to make a reliable 6v supply. 4 x 1.5 x 2.
Then use a 5v regulator to get a 5v rail and use a 3.3v regulator from the 5v to get a 3.3v rail.

I know there is not much detail about the circuit here but my question is really about the battery formation.

Should I instead create two seperate power sources to match my reails. Should I create a separate power source for my servos and have 4 rails (2 of each) Should I group the batteries to get a heigher voltage like 7.5 or 9

Ideally I would want all batteries to drain at the same rate so it's easy to replace them as they will all be dead at the same time

The number and size of batteries is fixed but most other things are up for grabs. I can provide more detail on anything if needed.

Comment: What do you consider to be the best idea? You hold all the cards on your specific intent and anyone reading this are in-the-dark.

Comment: AA batteries start out at around 1.6V per cell (or a tiny bit under) and drop down to around 1V per cell or even less as they discharge. So I don't think it is a good idea to use 4 cells in series to power a 5V regulator. If it is an LDO or a buck, it will drop out long before the batteries are discharged. If it is a boost, it will provide too high of a voltage when batteries are fresh. It is awkward. I think you should consider a single series stack. Then both your regulators can be buck types. Batteries in parallel can sometimes have high balancing currents (if old and new cells are mixed).

Comment: I guess best would be defined as:  a formation thats 'Safe' and 'efficient' Where all the components get the power they need without risk of voltage drop or other electrical anomalies.

Comment: @mkeith, Nice comment. Lots of good ideas in there. Douse sound like 8 batteries in series is a better idea based on your description of their behavior. I will definitively look into buck regulators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the batteries in series to ensure they all drain at the same rate. In parallel, variations in the batteries used might cause one branch to try to charge the other. The other advantage is you can then feed the whole lot into a buck converter to generate a 5V output which will be able to drain the batteries down completely.

If cost is not an issue I would just use a high performance buck IC, such as those made by Linear Technologies. These have very low standby current and are extremely efficient. However a complete implementation would cost upwards of $4-5. A cheaper option would be to power your micro with a cheap linear regulator, and have it turn on a cheap buck converter whenever the servos are required. Whether you need to put another buck converter to go from 5V to 3.3V depends on how much efficiency you're trying to squeeze out of the thing and, of course, how much you can afford to spend.

Comment: Within reason money is not a problem. The aim her is to get the design correct. Is it best to convert the ~12v from batteries into 5v and then 5v to 3.3v? or create both rails directly from the batteries? I had read that 12->5>3.3 is the most efficient but would like to know your opinion.

Comment: Most likely it will be more efficient to generate both rails directly from the battery (assuming you use buck regulators). If you are going to use an LDO for 3.3, then you should run the LDO from the 5V output of the buck. Pay attention to power sequencing. Does it matter which voltage comes up first? Will something bad happen if 5V turns on before 3.3V? What about the other way around?